# How to find error from LogCat in android?

Tags: android, logcat

Method or Hint for finding error from LogCat.
How to find and solve error from Logcat?

Comment: Please post the logcat, then we can talk you through it.

Comment: Error will be shown in red color. In eclipse click on DDMS perspective. In DDMS perspective, left panel, select emulator (or the device listed). And you will get the logcat.

Comment: What do you mean by "find"? The error usually gets printed in LogCat as it does in a normal java program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this approach:

```
adb logcat -s System.err
```

Answer (score 5):

I try to explain on a very basic example of logcat output taken from different post :

```
12-13 12:41:57.052: W/System.err(542): org.json.JSONException: No value for TAG_CONTACTS
12-13 12:41:57.052: W/System.err(542):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
12-13 12:41:57.052: W/System.err(542):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
12-13 12:41:57.052: W/System.err(542):  at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:56)
12-13 12:41:57.063: W/System.err(542):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-13 12:41:57.063: W/System.err(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-13 12:41:57.063: W/System.err(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-13 12:41:57.063: W/System.err(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-13 12:41:57.063: W/System.err(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-13 12:41:57.063: W/System.err(542):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 12:41:57.072: W/System.err(542):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-13 12:41:57.072: W/System.err(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-13 12:41:57.072: W/System.err(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 12:41:57.072: W/System.err(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-13 12:41:57.072: W/System.err(542):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
```

As you can see from first line exception is "JSONException" which heppened because of "No value for TAG_CONTACTS". From line number 4 you can see, that it happened in "AndroidJSONParsingActivity" on line 56. Now when you know what is the exception and where it happens, you should be able to solve it !

Answer (score 3):

In LogCat you will find among all those run time errors there is a tag "Caused by" under text attribute.you will click the next line of that error and that will point you to the code where that error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio You will See Logcat in Bottom switch to error in that and you have to read all red messages . these are errors